# AWS Reactive Response handler downloads partial file with WARN "Subscriber cancelled before all events were published"

Tags: amazon-s3, spring-webflux, reactive

I am using where awssdkversion = 2.10.1

```
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux"
implementation platform("software.amazon.awssdk:bom:$awssdkVersion")
implementation "software.amazon.awssdk:s3"
implementation "software.amazon.awssdk:netty-nio-client"
```

and trying to download the file from s3 using s3client.getObject but getting

```
2022-01-26T02:08:45.607+0000 - WARN - ResponseHandler : message="Subscriber cancelled before all events were published", timestamp="2022-01-26T02:08:45.607+0000", thread="aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-1", level="WARN", class="software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.ResponseHandler"
```

Not sure why am I getting it and what should be solution

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer the question without seeing the code. I did experience the same error. So below answer is based on that.

- In my scenario we were using AWS SDK V2 to read files from S3 and then process it. Faced this problem when in our processing code we were returning `Mono.empty()` for a use case and apparently that marks the end of the processing in the reactive pipeline. So we had to return `Mono.just("")` and handle our use case to check for "" string in the response.
- Similarly in the other processing bit, we were returning `Stream.empty()` in else block when we dont find results, which kind of blocking the pipeline flow. So instead return `List.of()` and then let the caller call the `.toList()` to mark the process completion.
- Another thing which could help you is to check for ThreadPool Executor in your Async S3 Client configuration. If for downloading of a large file is getting timed out or threads getting exhausted.

  ```
   S3AsyncClient asyncClient() {
       SdkAsyncHttpClient httpClient =
    NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.builder().writeTimeout(Duration.ZERO).maxConcurrency(64).build();
   return S3AsyncClient
       .builder().httpClient(httpClient).region(Region.of(s3ConfigProperties.getRegion())).asyncConfiguration(b -> b
           .advancedOption(SdkAdvancedAsyncClientOption.FUTURE_COMPLETION_EXECUTOR, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)))
       .build();
  ```

  }